# Write output of console.log to file - AWS Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, aws-sdk

I want to write the output of my javascript to a file using **[fs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html)**. But I noticed that fs doesn't work when I put **fs.appendFile()** inside my 
**ec2.describeSpotFleetRequests()**. Any workaround for this kind of situation?

Sample code:

```
fs.appendFile('./spotfleet.txt', 'Hello world!', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('It\'s saved!');
});

ec2.describeSpotFleetRequests(params,function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else {
        for (var fleet in data.SpotFleetRequestConfigs) {
            reqId = data.SpotFleetRequestConfigs[fleet].SpotFleetRequestId; // gets spot fleet ID
            fs.appendFile('./spotfleet.txt', 'Hello world!', (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('It\'s saved!');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The first fs.appendFile will write "Hello world!" to spotfleet.txt but the second fs.appendFile wouldn't run.

Comment: use control flow library [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/), May functions like `async.series([fn1,fn2,fn3],function(){ })` may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As szymonm mentioned in his answer, `fs.appendFile()` is asynchronous so I cannot call it in the loop. Good thing there is an [`fs.appendFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_file_data_options) for synchronous version. Why I didn't notice it before, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using some external libraries like [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)? It has built-in support for saving logs to a separate file:

```
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'spotfleet.txt' })
```

or do it with `configure()` call:

```
winston.configure({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'spotfleet.txt' })
    ]
})
```

All the logs you triggered by using, e.g.:

```
winston.info('Hello world!')
```

Will be saved to desired file. It's more elegant than `console.log` too...

**UPDATE:**

Because you edited your question with giving a code example, I see what's the problem here.

`fs.appendFile` is **asynchronous**, so you cannot call it in the loop the way you did.

Once one `fs.appendFile` operation is done, use the callback to save another thing.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try using winston. Can I get back to you if I encounter any problem?

Comment: Sure, feel free to :)

Comment: @Yvanne could you please accept my answer if it's correct? :-)

Comment: Since you said that fs.appendFile() is asynchronous, I used fs.appendFileSync() instead.